# Merge two dataframes that share multiple column names without overriding values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have two datasets about a dating app. Dataset 1 has all users and looks like this.

```
id, sign_up_date, gender, age
1   2017-09-03,   "Male", 24
2   2018-10-02,   "Female", 22
..................
```

Than I have a dataframe containing all likes that have ever been sent on the  app which is a very simple dataframe that looks like this:

```
sender_id, receiver_id, date
1,         2,          , 2018-10-03
2,         1,          , 2018-10-04
....
```

In this case user 1 and 2 are a match. I want to attach the gender of the sender and the receiver to this dataframe and whether or not is it a same sex like. So I want a dataframe that looks like this:

```
sender_id, sender_gender, receiver_id, receiver_gender, same_sex_like
1, "Male", 2, "Female", False
```

How would I go about this? I have tried joining the two dataframes however I'm not sure how to do this because the columns such as sign_up_date are the same.

I have also tried mapping however the dataframe is very big and my laptop is quite slow so that didn't really work either so far.

Any suggestions to get the dataframe I want? Thanks alot :D

dataframe 1 which shows all the users

Comment: 'match' is when there is sender_id -> reciver_id and reciver_id -> sender_id? Is date somehow important?

Comment: you may start with `df2.merge(df1[['id', 'gender']], right_on = 'id', left_on='sender_id', how='left')`

Answer (score 0):

This will require two joins using dplyr.

```r
output = df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("sender_id" = "id")) %>%
  rename(sender_gender = gender) %>%
  select(sender_id, sender_gender, receiver_id, date) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("receiver_id", "id")) %>%
  rename(received_gender = gender) %>%
  select(sender_id, sender_gender, receiver_id, receiver_gender, date)
```

After each join we use `rename` and `select` to ensure that the column of interest is kept. If we did not do this then dplyr would automatically rename the columns with identical names.

Some things to keep in mind when joining table with duplicate column names:

- If you do not use the `by =`  argument to tell dplyr which columns to join on, then dplyr will join on all column names that are identical.
- Only one copy of the columns that are used for the join are kept in the output. So joining by columns with identical names is not a problem.
- If there are some columns with identical column names that are not used in the join, dplyr renames these automatically. Each `*_join` function has a `suffix =`  argument. These suffixes are added to the column names of identical tables. The defauls are `".x"` and `".y"` so if you joined `df1` to itself: `inner_join(df1, df1, by = "id")` then your output would include a `gender.x` and a `gender.y` column.